# Angular kendo-ui datepicker clear button

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datepicker

Is there a way to append a clear button to angular kendo-ui datepicker as below? I know how it can be done via JQuery but not sure how to do in angular https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/datetimepicker-clear-button. I already know how to add it as a separate button but my target is to add it as a part of the datepicker.

[image]

Comment: did you check this link https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendoui-datepicker-clear-button

Comment: Thanks, after checking this I implemented my own button to clear the date content.

Comment: it will help others if you put the came code, so that future finders will benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I did it.

On the HTML,

```
<kendo-datepicker 
    [ngClass]="fromdate-selector"
    [(ngModel)]="fromDate" placeholder="Enter Date..." [format]="'dd/MMM/yyyy'"></kendo-datepicker>
<span class="fromdate-separate"><b>|</b></span>
<span><button class="close-btn" (click)="clearDate()"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button></span>
```

On the TS,

```
public fromDate = null;
...
public clearDate(){
        this.fromDate = null;
}
```